# Is it important what is the current branch while doing git checkout -b?

Tags: git

Is it important if i am in a branch A, or branch B before i create a new branch C?

Do this:

```
git checkout A
git pull
git checkout -b "C"
```

gives the same result as:

```
git checkout B
git pull
git checkout -b "C"
```

?

Comment: The branch will be based on the currently checked out branch

Comment: Is it `git checkout -b C` you mean? `git branch` doesn't have an option `-b`

Comment: @Martin Sorry i ment git checkout -b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A branch is simply a pointer to a commit, and `branch`/`checkout -b` creates a branch pointing to the same commit as the branch you're currently in - so where you are indeed matters.

Comment: What are consequences of this?

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski If branch A and branch B don't point on the same commit, branch C will start with a  different code. This is a pretty important consequence

Comment: The branches point to different commits, so you're likely operating on entirely different commit history up to a certain common ancestor (which means a different state of the files).

Comment: sorry, it should be git checkout -b i am asking about

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.  In the first case, you branching `C` from branch `A`, while in the second case you are branching `C` from branch `B`.

Comment: Are there any consequences of branching from A, or branching from B?

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski It really depends on what your goals are.  Update your question and I can say more.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -b C
```

and

```
git checkout -b C HEAD
```

are equal.

There is no connection to the branch you happen to have checked out. If branch A and branch B point to the same commit, your two cases are the same.

But, if you do this instead:

```
git checkout -b C A
```

and

```
git checkout -b C B
```

Then they are no longer equal, even if branch A and B point to the same commit. When a branch is given as a third parameter, this is set as the upstream branch to be tracked.

Answer (score 1):

You have several correct answers now, but I think you are still puzzled.  A drawing might help.

In Git, each commit has a "true name": its hash ID.  You've seen these hash IDs in `git log` output by now.  They are big and ugly and look random—like commit `36438dc19dd2a305dddebd44bf7a65f1a220075b` in the Git repository for Git—and they are in general not useful to humans, but they are how Git itself locates commits, so they are very important.

Mere humans, though, prefer *names*.  So we have names like `master`: branch names.  A branch name simply stores one of these hash IDs.  The hash ID itself *is* the commit; the name, `master`, *remembers* `36438dc19dd2a305dddebd44bf7a65f1a220075b` for us, so that we only have to remember `master`.

Now, whenever you make a *new* commit, that new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  Let's look first at how this happens, and what happens with the branch name `master`.

Suppose we start with a tiny little repository with just three commits in it, and those three commits' hash IDs are `A`, `B`, and `C`.  Commit `C` itself remembers the hash ID `B`—that's `C`'s *parent* commit—and `B` remembers `A` as its own parent.  Commit `A`, being the very first commit, has *no* parent.  The technical term for this is a *root commit*, though you don't need to remember that (but you'll see it in Git's output when you make the very first commit in a new, empty repository).

The name `master`, of course, remembers `C` for us, so this is what the whole thing looks like right now:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master
```

We say that `master` *points to* `C`, `C` points to `B`, and `B` points to `A`.  The fact that `B`'s parent is `A`, and `C`'s parent is `B`, is embedded within `B` and `C` themselves.  Commits necessarily *always* point backwards, so we can draw this a little easier in text without the arrows:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Branch *names* like `master`, however, *move*.  Let's see how that happens when we add new commit `D`:

```
[do some work, so that we have something to commit]
$ git add -u    # pick up all the updates
$ git status
[git status output]
$ git commit -m 'some message'
[git commit output]
```

The new commit gets a new hash ID, which—lucky for us—is `D` instead of some actual horribly long commit hash.  `D` points back to `C`, because `C` *was* the tip of `master` when we started:

```
A--B--C--D
```

But now `master` needs to remember `D`, rather than `C`, because `D` is now the tip commit of `master`.  So Git puts hash ID `D` into `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

#### Branch names point to commits, so a *new* branch name must point to a commit

So, let's suppose we have a much bigger repository, with a whole dozen or so commits in it:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

(ok, 11 commits, if they start with `A`).  The name `master` identifies (points to) one particular commit—`H`, right now—and the name `develop` points to another particular commit, `K`.

If we want to make a *new* branch name, such as `feature`, we *must choose some commit for it to point-to*.

Let's say we're currently `on branch master`, as `git status` would say.  The way Git knows this is that the special name `HEAD` is "attached to" `master`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

If we run `git checkout -b feature`, Git will create the new name `feature`, and then switch to that branch by attaching our `HEAD` to it.  ***The current commit `H` stays the same here.***

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, feature (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Let's say we now make the 12th commit which gets hash ID `L`.  Git knows *which branch to update* by the fact that `HEAD` is attached to it:

```
             L   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Note that `master` did not move: only the name to which `HEAD` is attached moves, when we make the new commit.

If we wanted our new commit `L` to come after commit `K`, it's now clear that we should have been `on branch develop`, as `git status` would say, when we made the name `feature`.  Then we'd have started with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

as before, but done `git checkout develop` first, which would do two things simultaneously:

- check out commit `K` instead of commit `H`, and
- attach the name `HEAD` to `develop`

and it would now look like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Nothing *committed* has changed, but we're now `on branch develop` and our current commit is `K`, not `H`.  Now if we create a new branch `feature`, using our current commit, we'll get this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop, feature (HEAD)
```

and we are now ready to make our new commit as before.  This time, though, we'll end up with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
                 \
                  L   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

As [Martin said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48403130/1256452), you can actually combine the "switch commits" and "create new branch" steps into one big step, using `git checkout -b new-name commit-specifier`.  That is, if you're on `master` (commit `H`) and you want `feature` to start at commit `K`, you can use:

```
git checkout -b feature develop
```

to tell Git: *I'd like to create `feature`, but not where I am now, I want to switch to the commit identified by the name `develop` and *then* create `feature` and attach `HEAD` to `feature`, all at once.*

#### This can be pretty confusing at first

It really helps to stop and draw out part of your commit graph every once in a while.  Remember that, in Git, once you make a *commit*, that commit can *never be changed at all*.  That hash ID, as useless as `36438dc19dd2a305dddebd44bf7a65f1a220075b` may seem to humans, specifically identifies *that* commit, forever!  Nothing you do to your repository will change this, `36438dc19dd2a305dddebd44bf7a65f1a220075b` is still and always *that* commit.

***The commits themselves are permanent and unchanging.  The branch names move.***  Git *finds* the commits by starting from branch names—which find the *branch tip* commits—and working backwards, from commit to parent, then to the parent's parent, and so on.  (You *can* shuffle branch names around so that some existing commit can no longer be *found*.  In effect, this abandons the commit.  Git will eventually—generally after 30 days or more—delete it for real, after which it's really gone.  But until then, the hash ID still finds it, as long as you have the hash ID itself written down somewhere.)

For (much) more, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).